# Convertir un char array a uint8_t

Tags: c++, conversión-de-tipos

Tengo el siguiente array de caracteres:

```
char caracteres[10] = {'1', '2'};
```

Y el siguiente `uint8_t` (su tamaño es de 1 byte):

```
uint8_t resolucion;
```

Lo que quiero es almacenar el 12 (como número) dentro de la variable `resolucion`. He probado algunas cosas pero no me han funcionado. ¿Alguna sugerencia?

Comment: Qué hay exactamente en `caracteres` ? Porque no es lo mismo `1` que `'1'`. Lo comento por si ha habido algun error al copiar

Comment: @eferion Tienes razón! Realmente son carácteres. Lo edito!

Comment: No entiendo la pregunta: ¿quieres que en `resolución` se almacene `'1'` y `'2'` a la vez?

Comment: @Paula_plus_plus Sí! El problema es que leo información contenida en un texto XML. Guardo los carácteres en la variable carácteres (ya que solo puedo leer carácter a carácter), pero realmente estos carácteres hacen referencia a una resolución (un número). Por eso, necesito almacenar ese 12 (como número) en la variable numérica.

Comment: @Paula_plus_plus Quiere parsear la cadena `"12"` y guardar el `12`

Comment: @Kane12 ¿Quieres guardar el 12 como cadena (`"12"`) o como valor (`12`) dentro de `resolucion`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suponiendo que tienes esto:

```
char caracteres[10] = {'1', '2'};
```

Si no lo has hecho ya, deberías finalizar la cadena con `'\0'`:

```
char caracteres[10] = {'1', '2', '\0' };
```

Con lo que sería equivalente a esto:

```
char caracteres[10] = "12";
```

El paso a entero es tan simple como usar un bucle:

```
uint8_t resolucion = 0;
for( char* ptr = caracteres; *ptr; ++ptr )
{
  resolucion *= 10;
  resolucion += *ptr - '0';
}
```

Es decir, se itera por la secuencia de caracteres y a cada uno se le resta el dígito `'0'` (no hay que olvidar que el caracter es la representación de un número). Revisando una tabla ASCII es facil ver que:

```
'9' - '0' = 9
'5' - '0' = 5
'1' - '0' = 1
'0' - '0' = 0
```

Comment: Muchas gracias!

Answer (score 3):

Puedes convertir una cadena de caracteres en número con la utilidad [`std::stoi`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stol) (`s`tring `to` `i`nteger) presente en la cabecera [`<string>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/string):

```
char caracteres[10] = {'1', '2'};
uint8_t resolucion = std::stoi(caracteres);
```

Ten en cuenta que `std::stoi` devuelve `int` no `uint8_t`, por lo que se podría producir un estrechamiento de datos, pero si tu `resolución` siempre va a caber en 8bits no debería ser problema.

También hay que tener en cuenta que pasarle a `std::stoi` valores no transformables a número puede lanzar una excepción [`std::invalid_argument`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/invalid_argument).

Comment: Gracias! También funciona!